# Trying to create basic regex that accepts only 3 digits, no more, no less. Not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

new to regex here

I am trying to create a very basic pattern matching where user input has to be exactly 3 digits. In this example, for me it is invalid if I have less than 3. But any input with 3 or more digits is accepted.  Shouldn't this be invalid if its greater than 3 digits?? Am I doing something wrong here?

```
import re


pattern = "[0-9]{3}"

user_input = input()
if(re.search(pattern, user_input)):
    print("valid")
else:
    print("invalid")
```

Comment: This will match the `123` in `1234`. You might want `pattern = "^[0-9]{3}$"`

Comment: ok this makes sense thank you!  What if I needed to include a pattern that may or may not occur?  my pattern may be "000" or it may be "000-0000".  Is there a way to account for these possible characters?  I apologize I just started regex yesterday so i am brand new

Comment: Try `"^000(-0000)?$"`